# Using jQuery AJAX function in CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to know that "Can we use jquery ajax function in codeIgnitor?"
If so then give an example.

Answer (score 2):

yes this is possible.The below code is an example.please try this

```
var base_url='<?php echo base_url();?>';
$.ajax({
        url:  base_url+'controller_name/function_name',
        type: 'post',
        data: {your data set}, //for example {id:id,name:name} 
        success : function(resp){
            // do your stuff
        },
        error : function(resp){}
    });
```

in controller get the value with post method like

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

please let me know if you want any thing else.